# Can't locate BT/Bencode.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

Having some error using Bencode.pm .

> Error: Can't locate BT/Bencode.pm in @INC

I installed module from source Bencode-1.402.tar.gz being unable to use it. While searching module from CPAN it shows

```
Module id = Bencode
    CPAN_USERID  ARISTOTLE (Aristotle Pagaltzis <pagaltzis@gmx.de>)
    CPAN_VERSION 1.402
    CPAN_FILE    A/AR/ARISTOTLE/Bencode-1.402.tar.gz
    MANPAGE      Bencode - BitTorrent serialisation format
    INST_FILE    /usr/local/share/perl5/Bencode.pm
    INST_VERSION 1.402
```

Comment: Firstly check where the module was installed in your system (is it really in /usr/local/share/perl5/). And then check if "/usr/local/share/perl5/" is in @INC: perl -e "print join(':', @INC);". If the module folder isn't there then add the path to PERL5LIB env.

Comment: show your code that is trying to use Bencode.  Where is the BT coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you should use

```
use Bencode;
```

not

```
use BT::Bencode;
```

or you are trying to subclass it?